# Legendary Alligator bug [Story progress 100%]

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I have done the story 100%. But yet cannot see the legendary Alligator (bull gator) marker on the map nor can find it.
After playing the "COUNTRY PURSUITS" mission the bull gator Icon/Marker does not appear on the map and still, after completing the story (and re-playing the "COUNTRY PURSUITS" mission once more) there is no marker on the map.

Visited the area (where most of the youtube videos and Reddit posts mention) in different day times, yet no sign of the clue to investigate and no sign of the gator.

Is it a bug? has anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the **same problem** a few days ago.
Turns out that there was too much activity on the legendary area.

I suggest you go somewhere far and restart the game, wait some time or setup a camp (not nearby) and sleep.

Also, as @Matthew commented you must complete *That's Murfree Country* on **Chapter 5**, or it won't spawn.

That's the exact location where you'll find the **Legendary Alligator (Bull Gator)**:

[image: rdr2 legendary bull gator]